# Pandas equivalent of R dcast

Tags: python, r, pandas, dcast

Sorry I am new to R. I am looking to do a R dcast in python using pandas. The original R code is this:

```
dcast(wide_data, date+hour~lat+lon+level,value.var=c("Speed",'Speed2','Speed3', "Angle"))
```

I have tried a pandas function:

```
wide_data.pivot_table(index=['date', 'hour'], columns=['lat', 'lon', 'level'], aggfunc='mean', values=["Speed",'Speed2','Speed3', "Angle"]).reset_index()
```

However, this returns me values that do not match the R code, although the shape of the output is the same. It gives me same values regardless of if I use aggfunc as 'mean' or 'sum'

This is a sample output from R
[image]

This is a sample output from python
[image]

Shape of both outputs is 30137 x 2258

The data in R:

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(17167L, 17167L, 17167L), class = c("IDate", "Date")), 
hour = c(6L, 6L, 6L), lat = c(39, 39, 39), lon = c(27.25, 27.25, 27.25), 
level = c("0.995 sigma level", "10 m above ground", "100 m above ground"),
Speed = c(3.40587727318528, 2.50491516822427, 4.26085672136485), 
Angle = c(56.4965630175858, 57.3884631533085, 55.2283047278042), 
Speed2 = c(11.6, 6.2746, 18.1549), Speed3 = c(39.5081763689492, 15.71734071454, 77.3554276907067)),
row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"),
sorted = c("date", "hour", "lat", "lon", "level" ))
```

Comment: "The same values regardless" of `mean` or `sum` does suggest that no aggregation is actually happening, you get one value per combination (which seems to be inline with the `dcast` code which would give a message if a function was needed... the R code doesn't give a message, right?) Anyway, could you share a small reproducible example? Just a few rows should do it.

Comment: I shared some sample outputs

Comment: Outputs are a good end, but to really get started sample **inputs** are helpful. Please share as copy/pasteable text, not as pictures. In R, `dput()` is a nice way to share sample data, e.g., `dput(wide_data[1:3,. ])` for the first three rows. It's copy/pasteable and includes are structure and class information.

Comment: structure(list(date = structure(c(17167L, 17167L, 17167L), class = c("IDate", 
"Date")), hour = c(6L, 6L, 6L), lat = c(39, 39, 39), lon = c(27.25, 
27.25, 27.25), level = c("0.995 sigma level", "10 m above ground", 
"100 m above ground"), Speed = c(3.40587727318528, 2.50491516822427, 
4.26085672136485), Angle = c(56.4965630175858, 57.3884631533085, 
55.2283047278042), Speed2 = c(11.6, 6.2746, 18.1549), Speed3 = c(39.5081763689492, 
15.71734071454, 77.3554276907067)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), sorted = c("date", "hour", "lat", "lon", "level"
)